# Generate JsonSchema and validate with swagger request and response models

Tags: java, swagger, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have swagger files with  OAS3 and OAS2. With these swagger file I want to generate [Jsonschema](https://json-schema.org/) for API response and request payloads. So that when I invoke the API, I want to check if the API response is valid/invalid against the generated schema.Similarly when I pass the request payload, I want to valid if the request payload is valid/invalid against generated json schema.

Is there any Java library that can read the swagger OpenAPI specs and generate [Jsonschema](https://json-schema.org/) for request and response payloads?

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for, but https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/master/ can validate payloads directly against an OpenAPI schema.

Comment: I think there is no library in java at least that gives you schema from the given JSON payload, you might want to write it by yourself. or you can try https://jsonschema.net/home